# Cache expiration: How does hazelcast deal with non-synchronous clocks on cluster nodes

Tags: hazelcast

Assume I have two hazelcast nodes that do not have guaranteed synchronous `system times (don't ask why I would do that, this is just a hypothetical question):

Let's say node 1 has its absolute time set to 0 in the beginning (System.currentTimeMillis returns 0) and node 2 has its absolute time set to 1000.

I create a lock that is stored on node 1 and set its expiration time to 100 milliseconds. It expires at node 1 absolute time 100 and node 2 absolute time 1100. Now node 2 joins the cluster. I also retrieve the lock in the application running on node 2 (without trying to lock it of cource, because it's still locked on node 1). Now I am holding two ILock references to the lock, one in the application running on node 1 and one in the application running on node 2.

When I call operations on the ILock on node 2 it sees that the actual object (in the lock store) is located on node 1 so it calls the operation remotely on node 1. At this point we don't have problems with time differences yet. If we wait for 100 milliseconds node 1 is going to expire the lock.

But we don't wait. Instead we shut down node 1. The lock gets transferred to node 2 because node 1 is no longer available. During the transfer the LockResourceImpl.writeData method on node 1 writes the data of the lock to some buffer. Then this buffer gets transferred to node 2 and the LockResourceImpl.readData method reads it there and sets the values on itself.

As far as I can see the timestamps are just copied to the respective fields without taking into account that the clock might be different on node 2. This means that the expiration time will still be 100 (the absolute time set by node 1) whereas node 2 system time is 1000 already. This means the lock expires instantly even though it should not.

Did I understand this correctly? Is this actually a problem?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not a problem. It is standard behavior for lock owned by a node to be instantly released when that node dies. If you think about it, it does make sense since a dead node has no use for locks and if you are forcing a timed wait by using a lock on a different machine something is really wrong with your code.

Disclaimer: I have not investigated this issue, but the behavior described is standard with lock on clustered (including hazelcast) systems.

Comment: You are right if node 1 is holding and managing the lock in the beginning. But now suppose thread 1 on node 2 acquired the lock in the beginning. Node 1 goes down, taking the lock with it (incorrectly expiring while transferring it to node 2). Now a thread 2 on node 2 can acquire the lock even though it should still be held by thread 1 on node 2. If expiration is not done properly this is gonna break everything. And since hazelcast offers lock expiration I kind of expect it to do it properly...

Comment: (sorry was not available last 2 days). Can you actually replicate this? I would be interested in a confirmed answer. But AFAIK, in this case, even if node 1 goes down while transferring lock, the lock should be released and given to thread 1 of node 2. I can confirm that, at all times, the lock will only be held by one thread.

Comment: I can not replicate it, my opinion is just based on the sources I looked at. I currently can not do anything because I'm on vacation and I don't have my computer.

Comment: When you get back from vactaion, if you do find anything that goes against my description do share here. Always willing to learn :). Enjoy your vacation.